# How to connect to a mariadb database hosted on raspberry over the internet?

Tags: database, mariadb, remote-access

I have a web server hosted on a personal raspberry pi 3. It has MariaDB as its database. I want MariaDB database to be accessible from anywhere in the world. I use python script to connect to the MariaDB server. I don't have any idea of how to do it. I have tried the following things :

MariaDB database was bound to 127.0.0.1 so i replaced it with 0.0.0.0

I tried looking if my raspberry was accepting connections on port 3306. I used Telnet for that :

```
telnet 192.168.0.215 3306
```

But i got this response :

```
 5.5.5-10.3.23-MariaDB-0+deb10u1+}WxwoFN4■≈-☻┐ü§ZJCRR$Yt_\2#mysql_native_password
```

My python script works fine when i replace the URL with my raspberry's local network IP address. I don't know what else to try to connect to remote MariaDB database using my same python script.

Comment: seems telnet is working fine. So you should be accessible through code. Please try once with command or mysql client like: mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hIP -PPORT and share output.

Comment: Yes, the telnet output looks as expected. MariaDB server is reacable, and sends the first communication package that basically consists of its version information and the hash to use to exchange password information. (don't let the 5.5.5 prefix confuse there, this was added as some original MySQL connectors only understood single digit major version numbers)